# Can I copy the optimizer (state) from one model to another? [keras, tensorflow]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Assuming I create model A, which has a similar but not exactly the same architecture as the compiled model B. Can I compile model A as follows?

```
model_A.compile(model_B.optimizer,
                loss=model_B.loss,
                metrics=model_B.metrics,
                )
```

I am most worried that some values stored in the optimizer (e.g. updates, weights, ...) are specific to the model architecture and may yield a mismatch. Can somebody explain what exactly is happening when I perform such a copy? I couldn't extract helpful information from the [source code (l37ff)](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py).

P.s.: Is the state of the optimizer also copied this way? If not, can you copy it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

We can use optimizer from one model to another. Most of the optimizers takes learning rate, momentum, decay etc as arguments. model.compile initialises the weights according to your argument. optimizer only takes care of how you loss is propagated after its calculation.

We will change optimizer only to make our model converge faster for the given data.

But you may not be able to use the same loss function for different models(model b can be mse and model a can have softmax as its last layer). same holds true for accuracy too.

Comment: So the state of the optimizer (stored in optimizer.updates according to my understanding) is not copied this way?

Comment: if you are using keras there is nothing like model.optimizer, to train your model using model.fit() you will declare an optimizers in keras 'optimizers' like sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD("parameter") and then use the in your model.fit( optimizer = ) you can use the same sgd for both modelA and modelB

Comment: Hmm.. I don't get your answer. At least with my keras version (2.2.4) there is a model.optimizer and it can be set during compile time, not (only) during training see https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/ . Moreover, there is a state of the optimizer which can be saved according to https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model

Comment: in keras Model is an class which doesn't have a optimizer() method. optimizers like sgd belong to optimizer class. sorry model in my previous comment is an instance of class Model.